# I have a below specified scenarion and want the expected one with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried something like this but didn't find the desired output:

```
$('div').contents().filter(function() {
 return this.nodeType === 3; }).wrap( '<p></p>' ).end().filter( 'br' ).remove();
```

Current Scenario:

```
<div>
hello how r u- dummy Text
<br>
hie how -  dummy Text
<br>
<br>
Have a good day- dummy Text
Have a good day- dummy Text
Have a good day- dummy Text
</div>
```

Expected Result:

```
<div>
<p>
hello how r u- dummy Text
<br>
hie how -  dummy Text
</p>
<p>
Have a good day- dummy Text
Have a good day- dummy Text
Have a good day- dummy Text
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If you put your question in a phrase instead of desired output, it would be easier to produce an answer

Comment: If you're trying to remove all 'br' tags, why is there a 'br' tag in your expected output?

Comment: What is your question basically?

Comment: @Stan just guessing, but a double break is a paragraph boundary, a single break isn't.

Comment: @Mathletics yeah you're probably right, but his syntax would never produce the expected result so I was confused.

Comment: I want when there is a 1 <br> between two text lines that chunk should be wrapped into 1 <p> and if there is continuosly 2 <br> that should be removed.

Comment: My above code is removing all the  <br> & putting every data chunk into  <p>

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
$('div')
    .contents()
        .filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.trim(); 
        })
        .wrap('<p>')
        .end()
    .filter('br')
        .remove();
```

**Output:**

```
<p>
hello how r u- dummy Text
</p><p>
hie how -  dummy Text
</p>
<p>
Have a good day- dummy Text
Have a good day- dummy Text
Have a good day- dummy Text
</p>
```

I am right?

Here is the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x47bgrdc/4/)**

Comment: I want when there is a 1 <br> between two text lines that chunk should be wrapped into 1 <p> and if there is continuosly 2 <br> that should be removed.